# Indexing the datetime column in the csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to slice the column which contains datetime type in the csv file using pandas.

thanks in advance.

for ex: `data.csv`

```
Country,Player,Runs,ScoreRate,MatchDate,Weekday
Afghanistan,Mohammad Shahzad,118,97.52,16-02-2010,Tue
india,schin,112,98.02,16-03-2010,wed
```

I want to slice the column containing datetime format.

Comment: @bmu  data.dtypes[data.dtypes == pandas.datetime].index but it is listing all the columns. if u try same method for float or string it returns the desired float or string columns

Comment: Then you should post this in your question (you can edit it). It would be helpful if you could give some example data, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm planning to add a `usecols` option to the file readers for reading out individual columns. Probably for pandas 0.10 (later this month)

Answer (score 4):

If i understand your question correctly, thats how you can do it:

```
from pandas import *
```

Read in the data, index by MatchDate:

```
frame=read_csv("dates.csv",  parse_dates = True, index_col = 4)
print frame

                Country            Player  Runs  ScoreRate Weekday
MatchDate                                                         
2010-02-16  Afghanistan  Mohammad Shahzad   118      97.52     Tue
2010-03-16        india             schin   112      98.02     wed
```

Define two datetime object's that define the range that you want slice:

```
x=datetime(2010, 1, 5)
y=datetime(2010, 2, 25)
```

And slice it (get all rows, that have a `MatchDate` between `x` and `y`):

```
print frame.ix[x:y]
                Country            Player  Runs  ScoreRate Weekday
MatchDate                                                         
2010-02-16  Afghanistan  Mohammad Shahzad   118      97.52     Tue
```

If you just want to get a certain month or year, you can just do this:

`frame.ix['2010-2']`

```
            Country            Player  Runs  ScoreRate Weekday
MatchDate                                                         
2010-02-16  Afghanistan  Mohammad Shahzad   118      97.52     Tue
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful  But, What if for instance we don't know column 4 contains datetime values. And i want to slice datetime type column from csv.

Comment: i am not sure i understand. do you mean, that you only want to read rows that have certain datetime values? and to do that, you would still have to know what column contains datatime objects.